# Move org-mode subtree to another subtree using arrows

Tags: org-mode

With this tree structure:

```
* A
** A.1
** A.2
** A.3
a3a3a3a3a3a3a3
* B
* C
** C.1
*** C.1.1
*** C.1.2
*** C.1.3
** C.2
** C.3
```

… I can move `C.1` (with its children) up and down with `M-↑` and `M-↓`. Easy.

If I use `M-S-↑` and `M-S-↓`, only the `C.1` node is moved, without its children. Easy, too, however the Manual claims in http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html:

> `M-S-<up>`     `(org-move-subtree-up)`
>
> Move subtree up (swap with previous subtree of same level).
>
> `M-S-<down>`     `(org-move-subtree-down)`
>
> Move subtree down (swap with next subtree of same level).

… so, really, it should be the other way round. Nevermind, though.

Also, using `M-S-↑↓`, the `C.1` node can be moved out of its parent, `C`. When this happens, the `C.1` node *always keeps* its level (`**` in this case), no matter where it ends up.

Now, what I want to achieve is to move *the whole* `C.1` subtree, the whole branch with all the children, similarly, *out* of `C`, while keeping its `**` level.

This could be done with `org-refile` or killing the subtree `C-c C-x C-w` and yanking it at some new point, however, nothing beats the `↓` `↑` experience (especially when I’ve got to move hundreds of such trees after importing my notes from Wunderlist).

<sub>Using GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 and Org-mode version 8.3.2 (8.3.2-10-g00dacd-elpa).</sub>

Comment: how do you import notes from wunderlist? thanks!

Comment: @netawater, I **did** import them using my script, https://github.com/michalrus/org-import-wunderlist . If you want to synchronize it regularly, use `org-wunderlist`, but that doesn’t work well for me.

Comment: `avy-org-refile-child`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Try This

Using arrow keys to edit a nested tree structure can be confusing but is worth learning.

1. Place the cursor on `C.1` line.

   > **Note:** The cursor will remain on `C.1` line unless otherwise noted.

   ```
   * A
   ** A.1
   ** A.2
   ** A.3
   a3a3a3a3a3a3a3
   * B
   * C
   ** C.1
   *** C.1.1
   *** C.1.2
   *** C.1.3
   ** C.2
   ** C.3
   ```
2. Move `C.1` down to bottom of `C` with by typing <kbd>M-↓</kbd> repeatedly to preserve `C.2` and `C.3` branches.

   Outline should look like:

   ```
   * A
   ** A.1
   ** A.2
   ** A.3
   a3a3a3a3a3a3a3
   * B
   * C
   ** C.2
   ** C.3
   ** C.1
   *** C.1.1
   *** C.1.2
   *** C.1.3
   ```
3. Outdent entire `C.1` subtree by typing  <kbd>M-S-←</kbd>.

   Outline should look like:

   ```
   * A
   ** A.1
   ** A.2
   ** A.3
   a3a3a3a3a3a3a3
   * B
   * C
   ** C.2
   ** C.3
   * C.1
   ** C.1.1
   ** C.1.2
   ** C.1.3
   ```
4. Move `C.1` subtree above `C` subtree by typing  <kbd>M-↑</kbd>

   Outline should look like:

   ```
   * A
   ** A.1
   ** A.2
   ** A.3
   a3a3a3a3a3a3a3
   * B
   * C.1
   ** C.1.1
   ** C.1.2
   ** C.1.3
   * C
   ** C.2
   ** C.3
   ```
5. Indent `C.1` subtree under another subtree, e.g. `B`, by typing <kbd>M-S-→</kbd>

   Outline should look like:

   ```
   * A
   ** A.1
   ** A.2
   ** A.3
   a3a3a3a3a3a3a3
   * B
   ** C.1
   *** C.1.1
   *** C.1.2
   *** C.1.3
   * C
   ** C.2
   ** C.3
   ```

I'll add some additional tips and examples to my answer soon.

**Tested using**

> `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, NS apple-appkit-1343.14)`
>
> `org-version: 8.3.1`

Comment: A bit weird, but, I guess, it's the only way. Thanks! I don't know, however, why `M-S-↓↑` won't move the whole subtree. It would be really convenient.

Comment: @MichalRus, agreed, because `C-x C-t` (transpose-lines) already does what `M-S-<up>/<down>` does.

Answer (score 1):

I used `org-cut-subtree` and `org-yank` to accomplish this.

`GNU Emacs 27.1`
`Org mode version 9.3`

Comment: Alternatively, fold the subtree with TAB, then `C-k C-k`,  `C-y` at new place, then unfold.

Comment: Tried this, and it seems to work correctly with normal `org-mode`. But with `org-indent-mode` turned on, this does not work properly. It yanks somewhere in the middle of the headings. I always have `org-indent-mode` on, so it is tricky to use this. @NickD

Comment: I use `org-indent-mode` too and I've never had any trouble like that.